# Loaded javascript function is undefined

Tags: javascript, xpages

I am sure the answer to this is simple but I have researched possible answers for hours with no luck.

I am trying to call a JavaScript addToHomeScreen function from onClientLoad (Client Side script) which is loaded but I get the ReferenceError: addToHomeScreen is not defined.  The script loads from our script library and it does load.

My Custom Control source code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
        <xp:this.resources>

            <xp:script src="/addToHomeScreen.js" clientSide="true">
            </xp:script>

        </xp:this.resources>

        <xp:eventHandler event="onClientLoad" submit="false">
            <xp:this.script><![CDATA[addToHomeScreen()]]></xp:this.script>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:view>
```

return:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/web3/website.nsf/addToHomeScreen"></script>
....
....
<script type="text/javascript">
 function view__id1__id4__id5__id7_clientSide_onClientLoad(thisEvent) {
addToHomeScreen()}
```

Any ideas?  I have also tried to call it from afterPageLoad (server side)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be a timing issue. Try enclosing your method call in a XSP.addOnLoad() call:

```
XSP.addOnLoad(function(){
    addToHomeScreen();
});
```

Comment: Great. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please accept the answer as the correct answer.